# Error adding iframe with Shiny app to blogdown - Wrong URL is used

Tags: r, shiny, blogdown

I wish to add a Shiny app to a blogdown post using an iframe.
Referring to [these](https://medium.com/@ant.soetewey/how-to-embed-a-shiny-app-in-blogdown-df777596f7d7) instructions, I try to duplicate the example.

However, my iframe is empty.

Chrome > Inspect Element > Console says

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Far to the right of this message in the same window is:
http://127.0.0.1:4321/blog/how-to-embed-a-shiny-app-in-a-r-markdown-document_files/shiny-app-in-blogdown.jpeg

Which points to

> Not found:
> ./blog/how-to-embed-a-shiny-app-in-a-r-markdown-document_files/shiny-app-in-blogdown.jpeg

Clearly, a jpeg file is not a Shiny app.
Why is this happening?

Rmarkdown file

```
---
title: iframe Test
author: ''
date: '2020-09-11'
slug: iframe-test
categories: []
tags: []
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

Some text above

<iframe height="800" width="100%" frameborder="no" src="https://antoinesoetewey.shinyapps.io/statistics-201/"> </iframe>

Some text below
```

Since originally posting this question, I have restarted RStudio. Now the Inspect Element > Console does not show any errors yet the iframe is still empty.

Chrome > Inspect Elements
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you used to embed the app in your `blogdown` document?

Comment: Of course. See revised question.

Comment: That's strange - I can't replicate the problem.  I initialized a new blogdown site, deleted all of the content except the example .Rmd post.  I deleted all of the content in the file and replaced it with the content you posted and rendered the site.  In the viewer, the shiny app didn't show up, but if I viewed it in a web browser, it worked. [Here](https://quantoid.net/files/images/iframe_test.png) is the image.

Comment: You are correct. Externally hosted sites, such as a Shiny app, will not appear in RStudio's Viewer. "RStudio includes a Viewer pane that can be used to view local web content." - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane